# Click menu items from a Ext.menu.Menu

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button that once clicked, will expand a menu item, I want to be able to click one of those menu items programmatically through the java script console. Here's what i have for clicking the button, but need a little help on clicking the Ext.menu.Menu

```
var fireButton=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[itemId=buttonID]')[0]; //find button id
fireButton.fireEvent('click'); //open button/submenu
```

var ok = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('menuitem')[0]; //excess menu item

//how to click a menu item??

here's my menu:

```
menuButton: new Ext.menu.Menu({
    items: [
       {text: 'OK', value: 'ok'},
       {text: 'Next', value: 'next'},
    ],
    listeners: {
        click: 'onClickMenuButton',
    }

onClickMenuButtonItem: function(menu, item){
    this.makeVisible(menu, item);
},

makeVisible: function(menu, item){
        var menuItem = Ext.getCmp(item.value);
        menuItem.isVisible()){
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
        item.setIconCls('plusSign');
}),

var openMenu = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[itemId=buttonID]')[0];
openMenu.fireEvent('click', openMenu);
var clickMenu = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("menu")[0]
clickMenu.items.filter('text','OK').fireEvent('click'); //Don't work!
```

Comment: Why do you need to open the submenu to access it programatically? Is it already in the DOM?

Comment: testing purposes, Yes, it's already in the DOM. I just want to programmatically test it to see if it works as it should.

Comment: I see. Does your open subnav have a class or data attribute to show that it is open? If so, you can target that to click it.

Comment: what do you mean? It does have a class, and I can excess the same thing like above using jquery, but not successful getting the menu items.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write it in extjs, but in jQuery it'd look something like this: `$('.sub-menu-open .item').eq(itemId).find('a').trigger('click');`

Comment: i don't think the menu id have an class, only the button has a class.

Comment: Unless someone can think of some other way of targeting the opened submenu, I'm not sure it's possible without some sort of "hook" (a class or identifier).

Comment: When creating the menu items, if you could, assign a cls attribute (need not be an actual css class) then you can easily get a reference to the menu items by using that cls attribute that you assigned as a selector in your query.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this fiddle is somewhat what you are looking for -

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lai

Notice that I'm providing `cls: 'test'` in one of the dynamically created items and then I'm using `Ext.query(".test");` to get that item.

You can also search for the menuitem using this query -

```
var item = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('menuitem{text.search( \'Item 1\' )!=-1}');
item[0].fireEvent('click')
```

And the menu item will have to register a click listener as -

```
{
    text: 'Item 1' ,
    iconCls: 'add16',
    cls: 'test',
    listeners: {
        click: function(){
            console.log('clicked')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var ok Ext.ComponentQuery.query('menuitem{text.search( \'You menu item text\' )!=-1}'); ok.fireEvent('click'); how can i fire an event to that specific menu item search ? it doens't support fireEvent

Comment: The query will return an array of objects if they match the criteria. If you've a single item with that text then you can be sure that your array will contain only that item and this you can access as the first element of the array

Comment: ok, so it works but then, it's not doing what it's suppose to do, what its suppose to do is, once a menu item is clicked, it's suppose to set visiblity to a region of the webpage such as an table view or grid view. its not doin so.

Comment: Can you confirm if the click is fired? If so, then the subsequent problem can only be understood if you can show more of the code.

Comment: is there a way to confirm that? after running the code, it just return a "true"

Comment: You must have defined a click listener function!! If you listener is invoked than what you've written inside that function will be executed. To be sure, if you want to, add a console.log or an alert at the beginning to see if it is invoked. And I cannot comment as what is returning true without seeing some of the code.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, it is a button once click, will open an Ext.menu.Menu, i need to click an item off that menu.

Answer (score 0):

**xtype:menuitem** has a method called -[down](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item-method-down)- which will get you the first child. I'm not sure which version you're using so I'm linking to the latest docs; however, 4.x has this method as well.

It's worth noting that [down](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item-method-down) can also take a selector as a parameter.

for ex (using cmp where itemid is set):

```
this.down("#itemidvaluehere")
```

**EDIT**

update after your update showing your menu:

I would try it like this from the console:

```
var mn=Ext.ComponentQuery.query("menu")[0]
mn.items.filter('text','OK').fireEvent('click');
```

Comment: what if your menu items don't have an itemID ? by the way, there's no xtype:menuitem, it's only a button that once click will show sort of an menu with items to be able to click, is that still the same?

Comment: To answer your first question: you can use a component query : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery . As for your second question, I have to ask if you are using a standard extjs menu? Can you add more code to your OP to help clarify the objects you're working with a little better.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, it is a button once click, will open an Ext.menu.Menu, i need to click an item off that menu.

Comment: see if this fiddle is what  you're trying to accomplish:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lap  NOTE: I Did not do the expand menu..just the click of the menu item.

Comment: yeah, but I'm trying to do this through the java script console, programmatically click it.

Comment: Click the button?  
Ext.getCmp("buttonidhere").fireEvent('click');

Comment: not the button, i already can click the button, i need to click the menu items

Comment: exchange the button id with the menu item id, OR get access to the menu and use the down() function. 
ex: 
Ext.getCmp("menuItemIdHere").fireEvent('click')

Comment: the menu items don't have id's. they are just text. here's an example of the menuitem/button, updated my post.

Comment: Ok, i see what's happening, there's no event happening when click on an menu item, what happens once clicked, is it just set a container id to visible(true) or visible (false). How can i mimic that action?